# сортировка от min до max jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sort">
  <div data-price="1">item with price 1</div>
  <div data-price="2">item with price 2</div>
  <div data-price="3">item with price 3</div>
  <div data-price="4">item with price 4</div>
  <div data-price="5">item with price 5</div>
  <div data-price="6">item with price 6</div>
  <div data-price="7">item with price 7</div>
</div><br>
Сортировка: 
<div class="sort-by-price">
  <input type="text" id="price_min" placeholder="Min">
  <input type="text" id="price_max" placeholder="Max">
</div>
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы при изменении значения в input - скрывались/показывались(т.е display:none/block) div. Соответсвенно указав в input`ах значение 3 и 7 - показались только элементы начиная с третьего, и заканчивая седьмым.

Comment: Проход каждого элемента, проверка условия и, если нужно, скрывать/открывать.

Comment: Если подряд идут - можно оптимизировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var $price_min = $('#price_min'),
    $price_max = $('#price_max'),
    $dataPrice = $('[data-price]');
    
function showAndHide() {
  var price = {
      min: parseFloat( $price_min.val() ) || 1,
      max: parseFloat( $price_max.val() ) || $dataPrice.length
    };
    
  $dataPrice.each(function() {
    var my_price = parseFloat( $(this).data('price') );
    
    if( my_price >= price.min && my_price <= price.max ){
      $( this ).show();
    }else{
      $( this ).hide();
    };
  });
};
    
$price_min.on('input', showAndHide);

$price_max.on('input', showAndHide);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sort">
  <div data-price="1">item with price 1</div>
  <div data-price="2">item with price 2</div>
  <div data-price="3">item with price 3</div>
  <div data-price="4">item with price 4</div>
  <div data-price="5">item with price 5</div>
  <div data-price="6">item with price 6</div>
  <div data-price="7">item with price 7</div>
</div><br>
Сортировка: 
<div class="sort-by-price">
  <input type="text" id="price_min" placeholder="Min">
  <input type="text" id="price_max" placeholder="Max">
</div>
```